# Cannot Query Neo4j Repositories

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Hey everyone I am fairly new to Neo4j and am having an issue querying my repositories.

Repository is the follow:

```
   public interface NodeOneRepository extends GraphRepository<NodeOne> {
       List<NodeOne> findByNodeTwoNodeThreeAndActiveTrue(NodeThree nodeThree);
   }
```

My entities are the following:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "NodeOne")
public class NodeOne {
  @GraphId
  private Long id;

  private Boolean active = TRUE;

  @Relationship(type = "IS_ON")
  private NodeTwo nodeTwo;
}

@NodeEntity(label = "NodeTwo")
public class NodeTwo {
  @GraphId
  private Long id;

  @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS", direction = "INCOMING")
  private NodeThree nodeThree;

  @Relationship(type = "IS_ON", direction = "INCOMING")
  private List<NodeOne> nodeOnes = new ArrayList<>();
}

@NodeEntity(label = "NodeThree")
public class NodeThree {
  @GraphId
  private Long id;

  @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS")
  private List<NodeTwo> nodeTwos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Getters & Setters omitted. When I call the method I get an empty list. Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't describe exactly what you wanted to achieve, but I can see two problems:

**Problem 1:**

The current version of Spring Data Neo4j and OGM only allow nested finders, that is, finders that specify a relationship property, to one depth.

*Supported*

`findByNodeTwoSomePropertyAndActiveTrue(String relatedNodePropertyValue)`

*Not Supported*

`findByNodeTwoNodeThree //Nesting relationships in finders is not supported`

**Problem 2:**

Derived Finders Allow Matching Properties and Nested Properties. Not a whole instance of that class.

You can probably achieve what you would like using a custom query.

```
@Query("custom query here")
List<NodeOne> findByNodeTwoNodeThreeAndActiveTrue(NodeThree nodeThree);
```

If you need help to write a custom query, you can post another question or join the neo4j-users public slack channel.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Based on documentation though it states that you can query by an instance of a class something like `findByNodeTwo(NodeTwo nodeTwo)` but this is not the case as it keeps returning no value. Even with depth set to 1. See example 3 http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_query_and_finder_methods. Is this incorrect? Should the docs be updated? @jasper-blues

Comment: I'm not familiar with this feature - either it has been recently added, or the documentation is misleading. (If its the former, the docs need more details). I'm going to head over to `neo4j-users.slack.com` and ask for you. Feel free to join too.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up in the Slack. I added an additional question in the Slack as well. Hopefully we can get a response soon!

Comment: Didn't get clarification there yet. I'm interested myself anyway, so will try to make time to check out the code and see tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! From my findings it seems that i have to write a custom `@Query` when using a class object as a parameter and when those class objects reference a relationship. Let me know your findings if you are able to do this differently.